# mysql:show date from datetime

Tags: php, mysql

i have a field inside table inspection,it is inspection_datetime.
the type of field is datetime, so that make the data like `yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`.
my question is how do i do if i want to show date only from the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few solutions, including formatting the data in SQL or in PHP as given in other answers.

Another option is to return just the date portion from the datetime column:

```
SELECT DATE(inspection_datetime) FROM inspection
```

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use Date_Format if you want MySQL to do it:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inspection_datetime, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to PHP 5.3.0 or greater, the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function makes formatting dates and times easy:

```
$dt = new DateTime($db_datetime);

echo $dt->format('Ymd');
// 20101231

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
// 2010-12-31

echo $dt->format('Y-M-d');
//2010-Dec-31
```