# How to select certain data from a same field

Tags: php

Now currently facing a problem that is..
My table name is schedule 
One of the data field is 'Depart'
the record is

```
row 1 = 19-08-2012 08:00:00AM,
row 2 = 19-08-2012 12:00:00PM,
row 3 = 20-08-2012 07:00:00PM,
```

I just want to display the date only and it is distinct

```
mysql_query(Select distinct depart from schedule);
```

This display date and the time.
Any one here know how to display the date only?

Comment: IT is duplication of previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360068/mysqlshow-date-from-datetime

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example

SQL (recommended)

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE( depart ) 
FROM `tbl`
```

PHP

```
$d = "19-08-2012 08:00:00AM";
echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($d));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT()` function in the Mysql, as follows :

```
select DATE_FORMAT(distinct(Depart),'%m-%d-%Y') from schedule
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `DATE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(`depart`) FROM `schedule`
```

Comment: my depart field is DateTime Type. 

SELECT DISTINCT DATE(`depart`) FROM `schedule`
no out put display..